# How to prevent spam request in Servlet

Tags: servlets

I'm writing a small servlet to prevent spam requests from an J2ME app. But, i don't know how to do this.

Could you help me or suggest to me some links/posts about this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have another Servlet that handles 'valid' requests and you want spam requests to be filtered out?

If that is so, then you need a **[Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)**.

You would configure it in your `web.xml` (or by annotation) to be applied to all requests going to your actual Servlet and implement it like that:

```
public class SpamFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // maybe read some configuration, e.g. rules that say what is spam and what is not
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (isValidRequest(request)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // request is spam, prevent further processing (so, do nothing)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```